# Where relationship column equals?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, shoes

I am trying to grab all records where Player's relationship called `stats()` has a column value of something. I would usually do `::where('column_name' 'column_value')` for the players table, but how can I get ::where the relationship table's column equals to something?

```
Player::where('column_name', 'column_value')->get();
```

But I want to check a column in the relationships table?

```
public function roleplay()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Database\Frontend\User\Roleplay', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Check this section in Laravel's documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This will filter Player based on a related table

```
Player::whereHas('roleplay', function($q){
   $q->where('column_name', 'value');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the ticket!

Answer (score 22):

Laravel 8^ : doc [Relationship Existence Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

```
Product::with('categoreys')->whereRelation('categoreys', 'status', '0')
                                            ->get();
```

Comment: That's just a shortened way of writing of @oseintow's answer

Comment: Please note that by using `with` two database queries will be executed. The accepted answer that uses `whereHas` will result in a single query.

Comment: It's a good (or at least 'clean') way for nested relationships. Thanks.